# Algebraic/étale representation varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

There has been extensive study of representation varieties $R(S, G)$ which are moduli spaces of representations of the fundamental group of a compact Riemann surface $S$ into a reductive group $G$. Concretely $R(S, G)$ is the quotient $\operatorname{Hom}(\pi_1(S), G)/G$ for conjugation action of $G$. It inherits an analytic structure from $G$. $R(S, G)$ can be identified with the moduli space of flat $G$-connections over $S$. This can in fact be done for arbitrary compact manifolds $M$ in place of $S$, and possibly in even greater generality.

Since Riemann surfaces can arise as complex points of smooth projective algebraic curves, it is natural to ask if algebraic counterparts of this construction and identification exist as well, so:

Fix a field $k$. Take a scheme $S$ and a reductive algebraic group $G$ over $k$. Consider the functor $\underline{\rho}^{ét}_{S,G} = \operatorname{Hom}(\pi^{ét}_1 (S), G)$, see if it is representable by a (formal - see R. van Dobben de Bruyn's comment below) scheme $\rho^{ét}_{S,G}$, take its GIT-quotient by the conjugation action by $G$, and call the resulting (formal) stack $R^{ét}_{S,G}$.

Or perhaps it'd be more appropriate to take one of the constructions of the fundamental group scheme of $S$, e.g., by Nori or Vakil-Wickelgren, instead of $\pi^{ét}_1 (S)$, and consider the analogous stack $R_{S,G}$ when it exists.

Some basic questions are:

(1) Can this be done always or only for certain $k, S$ and $G$? In which cases does one obtain a scheme rather than a stack? When and in what form does identification with the moduli space of flat $G$-connections over $S$ still hold?

(2) If $S$ is a smooth projective algebraic curve $C$ over $\mathbb{C}$, how are $R_{C,G}(\mathbb{C})$ and $R^{ét}_{C,G}(\mathbb{C})$ related to the representation variety of the associated Riemann surface, $R(C(\mathbb{C}), G(\mathbb{C}))$?

(3) If $k$ is a number field or a $p$-adic field, $S = \operatorname{Spec}(k)$ and $G = \operatorname{GL}_n$, what is $R^{ét}_{S,G} := \operatorname{Hom}(\operatorname{Gal}(\overline{k}|k), \operatorname{GL}_n)//\operatorname{GL}_n$? How are its $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_l$-points related to the deformation spaces of $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_l$-valued Galois representations (via connected components over residual representations?) What is $R_{S,G}$ in this case?

(4) What is a good reference for all this?

Comment: Because the étale fundamental group is profinite, it is more natural to ask for $\operatorname{Hom}(\pi_1^{\operatorname{\acute et}}(S),G)$ to be represented by a formal scheme or rigid analytic space. The coefficients of a local system are usually taken $\ell$-adic, so the same should apply to the space of such local systems.